# How can I connect ListView to CustomListView

Tags: android

firstly I made a listview then I want to make listview with icons. I do it for;(This is my custom adapter and of course I have a xml for it. It is listeozellikleri.xml)

```
public class listeozellikleri extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public listeozellikleri(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.liste_ozellikleri, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_ozellikleri, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logoisim);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logosimge);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values[position];

        System.out.println(s);

        if (s.equals("photo1")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        } else if (s.equals("photo2")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        } else if (s.equals("photo3")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
        } else if (s.equals("photo4")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

And this is my main listview;

```
    TextView dogrusonuc;
    TextView bossonuc;
    ListView sonuclistesi;
    Context context;

   //logo verileri icin adaptor acma baslangic
    ArrayList<String> veriler; {
    veriler = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    //logo verileri icin adaptor acma bitis

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //tam ekran kodu baslangic
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //tam ekran kodu bitis


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sonuclar);       

        //logo verileri cekme baslangic
        Intent veri = getIntent();  
        veriler = veri.getStringArrayListExtra("logoveri");
        //logo verileri cekme bitis

        //liste olusturma baslangic
        ListView sonuclistesi=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.sonuclistesi);
        ArrayAdapter<String> veriadaptoru=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, veriler);
        sonuclistesi.setAdapter(veriadaptoru);
        //liste olusturma bitis        

        //sonuclari yazdirma baslangic
        dogrusonuc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dogrusonuc);
        dogrusonuc.setText("doğru sayınız: " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("dogruveri"));

        bossonuc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bossonuc);
        bossonuc.setText("boş sayınız: " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("bosveri"));
        //sonuclari yazdirma bitis

    }
    private AbsListView sonuclistesi() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I connect custom adapter to main listview? Because I need to show datas with icons...
*When my intent add photo1 to my listview then image1 will be this item's icon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this -
        ArrayAdapter veriadaptoru=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, veriler);
        sonuclistesi.setAdapter(veriadaptoru);

Use below.

```
    listeozellikleri mAdapter = new listeozellikleri(this,veriler);
    sonuclistesi.setAdapter(veriadaptoru);
```

And it is good practice to have class names starting in caps. so listeozellikleri should be Listeozellikleri.

Also if veriler is an ArrayList, you should change String[] values in your adapter to ArrayList values.

Change your adapter as below

```
     public class listeozellikleri extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<String> values;

public listeozellikleri(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.liste_ozellikleri, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_ozellikleri, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logoisim);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logosimge);
    textView.setText(values.get(position));

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values.get(position);

    System.out.println(s);

    if (s.equals("photo1")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
    } else if (s.equals("photo2")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
    } else if (s.equals("photo3")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
    } else if (s.equals("photo4")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

}

Comment: The constructor Listeozellikleri(sonuclar, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

Comment: make sure veriler and  values in adapter should be the same type. What type is veriler? String[] or Arraylist<String>

Comment: It is Arraylist<String> .. Look up my code i past all of them?

Comment: But in adapter values is String[] how can I convert adapter String[] TO Arraylist<String> ??

Comment: Then String[] values should be changed to ArrayList<String> in your adapter. Change that and app should run.

Comment: how can I convert adapter String[] TO Arraylist<String> ??

Comment: I have edited my answer. Just update your adapter like how i have given.